# navigation bar color changes after new view is presented due to rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, rootviewcontroller

i am going from menu viewControler to InboxViewConroller through segue.

As the inbox view present and from the background menuview discarded the navigation bar color on inbox view goes darker due to the root view controller.

I found the issue but what is the appropriate solution for this problem.

I tried by putting an empty view on the inbox view and it works but it is not the solution.

please help me out.

[image: firstImage]

[image: SecondImage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: thanks @Versus. It worked. You made my day. Thanks aton.